# jQuery breaking my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Good day

I am including jquery in my header.php file like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

But when doing this, it breaks my home page slider, it breaks my google maps ultimate plugins and some other things. When I exclude it, no custom jquery runs on my page...only the slider works which must be using jquery...

So if jquery is already running on my site (since I have jquery easing in the theme etc..), why is custom jquery code I add to my files in  tags not working? However, when I include jquery like I said above, my custom code runs, but it breaks other plugins...

Why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your custom jQuery code is not running with the existing jQuery included by WordPress is probably because WordPress's jQuery is set up with [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). The noconflict method relinquishes the "$" shortcut used in jQuery. This means that code that relies on it, e.g.

```
$("p").hide();
```

...won't work, as $ will not represent a jQuery obejct. Try wrapping your custom code like this, which is the standard way of getting the $ object back (example taken from [this page](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
/* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
    $("p").hide();
});
```

This is done because several different JavaScript libraries use `$` as a "shortcut" variable (e.g. [MooTools](http://mootools.net)), and third-party WordPress plugins and themes often include other JavaScript libraries. Relinquishing `$` and making you specify exactly which object you really mean to use is a way of ensuring the least conflict when several libraries are loaded into a single page by WordPress.

So, I'd say that ensuring WordPress's standard version of jQuery is available to your theme (probably using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your functions.php) as shown in [tip one here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/):

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

...and then using it in your own functions by adding the "map-jQuery-back-to-$" wrapping method above would be best for all-round compatibility. Most current WordPress themes and plugins that require jQuery will be written to use the shipping version of jQuery with WordPress, and you should probably do the same.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery 1.9.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/) deprecated a lot of functions.  Try using [jQuery Migrate 1.1.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) or downgrade to 1.8.3

Comment: thank you gmartellino - didn't know jQuery 1.9.1 is having compatibility issues - Will use 1.8.3 from now on to be safe.